# how can i use the jquery validation plugin manually...ex. respond to a button click and not to a form post?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm new to the validation plugin. I'm trying to validate a couple of input fields that are going to be used in a $.post call, but I'm stuck in the very first step. How can I validate this groups of elements, that are not in a form, just a plain div.

In this attempt I receive this exception: Cannot call method 'element' of undefined

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var validator = $('.formulario').validate({
    rules : {
      nombre: "required",
      password: "required"
    },
      messages: {
      nombre: "Este campo es requerido",
      password: "Este campo es requerido"
      }
    });

    $('[name=procesar]').click(function () {
      if ($('.formulario').valid()) {
        alert('valid');

      } else {
        validator.showErrors();
      }
    });
  })

</script>

<div class="formulario">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"/>
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  <input type="button" name="procesar" value="click"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I never used jquery validate but I know it needs to be called on a form element. Can you not use form instead of div?

Comment: I test the code using a form and works....but I have so much code without the form tag that refactoring will be a task of a couple of hours..I'm trying to avoid doing that.

Comment: well it would be better code if you change them to form instead of the divs. Or maybe you can just wrap the divs in forms using jquery. I would still change it in the markup, even though it is a lot of work but it'll perform better

Comment: thanks @Huangism, your comments may have been a good answer

Comment: that's ok I never used validate so I will leave the answering to professionals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can trigger the validation tests with all kinds of events and button elements... both inside and outside of a `form`, and all *without requiring* a "post" of the `form`.

However, you *absolutely cannot* attach `.validate()` to any container other than a `<form></form>` element.

There is no workaround for this.

**Documentation:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation**